# MYSQL: Getting an error while updating table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, sql-update

I have written below query to update mysql table

```
update table1
set val_col = 'TRUE'
where id IN(
SELECT ID  
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.a_id = b.a_id
WHERE a.create_dt >= '2017-01-07' AND
      b.check_status = 'FAIL' AND
      b.check_type = 'check1' AND
      b.timestamp_val = (SELECT MAX(b2.timestamp_val)
                         FROM table2 b2
                         WHERE b2.a_id = b.a_id AND
                               b2.check_status = b.check_status AND
                               b2.check_type = b.check_type
                        ));
```

I am getting an error

`You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear that tells, you are trying to update `table1` but `table1` also used in the where clause. So, creating an inner select and aliasing it should do the trick;

```
update table1
set val_col = 'TRUE'
where id IN(
select * from (
SELECT ID  
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.a_id = b.a_id
WHERE a.create_dt >= '2017-01-07' AND
      b.check_status = 'FAIL' AND
      b.check_type = 'check1' AND
      b.timestamp_val = (SELECT MAX(b2.timestamp_val)
                         FROM table2 b2
                         WHERE b2.a_id = b.a_id AND
                               b2.check_status = b.check_status AND
                               b2.check_type = b.check_type
                        )) aliasTable1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 JOIN
       (SELECT ID  
        FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
             table2 b
             ON a.a_id = b.a_id
        WHERE a.create_dt >= '2017-01-07' AND
              b.check_status = 'FAIL' AND
              b.check_type = 'check1' AND
              b.timestamp_val = (SELECT MAX(b2.timestamp_val)
                                 FROM table2 b2
                                 WHERE b2.a_id = b.a_id AND
                                       b2.check_status = b.check_status AND
                                       b2.check_type = b.check_type
                                )
       ) tt
       ON t1.id = tt.id
    set t1.val_col = 'TRUE';
```

I suspect that you can also simplify the logic.